# Semisimple 6-dimensional Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am working on Exercise 10.7 of Erdmann & Wildon's "Introduction to Lie Algebras":

> Suppose $L$ is semisimple of dimension $6$. Let $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $L$ and let $\Phi$ be the associated set of roots.
>
> (i) Show that $\operatorname{dim}H=2$ and that if $\alpha,\beta\in\Phi$ span $H^{\star}$ then $\Phi=\{\pm\alpha,\pm\beta\}$.
>
> (ii) Hence show that $$[L_\alpha,L_{\pm\beta}]=0~\text{and}~[L_{\pm\beta},[L_{\alpha},L_{-\alpha}]]=0$$
> and deduce that the subalgebra $L_{\alpha}\oplus L_{-\alpha}\oplus[L_{\alpha},L_{-\alpha}]$ is an ideal of $L$. Show that $L$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of two copies of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbf{C})$.

I am able to show (i). For $[L_\alpha,L_{\pm\beta}]=0$, I believe it can be done by showing that if $\alpha+\beta\in\Phi$, then $\operatorname{Span}\{\alpha,\beta\}$ has dimension $1$, thus it is impossible that they span $H^{\star}$. This gives $[L_\alpha,L_\beta]\subseteq L_{\alpha+\beta}=0$.

Yet I have no idea how to do the rest of the problem. For the second part of (ii), I tried to show $[e_{\beta},[e_{\alpha},f_{\alpha}]]=0$ which is equivalent to $$0=[e_\beta,h_\alpha]=-[h_\alpha,e_\beta]=-\beta(h_\alpha)e_\beta=-\frac{2(\beta,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}e_\beta,$$
but then this means $(\alpha,\beta)=0$. Is it in general true that $\alpha,\beta$ are orthogonal? If so, how can I show this? I'm pretty sure this has to do with $\operatorname{dim}H=2$, but I couldn't work out the details here.

The book has not covered the classification of root systems yet, so it would be nice if a solution based purely on the properties of root space decomposition is given. Thanks!

Comment: It's not true that "if $\alpha + \beta \in \Phi$ then $Span\{\alpha, \beta\}$ has dimension 1". What is true very generally is that $[L_\alpha, L_\beta] \subset L_{\alpha+\beta}$, and if this last space were $\neq 0$, then $\alpha + \beta$ would be a root i.e. in $\Phi$, which you showed in part (i) it is not.

Comment: For your actual question, it is indeed true that in your situation $\alpha \perp \beta$, and if you have not seen the classification of root systems yet, you'll have to prove that from whatever you do know about root systems at this point. What exactly is that? For example, do you know what $s_\alpha (\beta)$ would be if $(\beta, \alpha) \neq 0$? Could it be any of the four roots $\pm \alpha, \pm \beta$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg sorry, can you clarify what is $s_\alpha$?

Comment: What, to you, is a root system? $s_\alpha$ is a reflection at the hyperplane perpendicular to $\alpha$, and usually these come up already in the definition of a root system. Sometimes they're called $w_\alpha$ or something.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg oh now I see it - the definition of root system comes after this exercise, so I didn't notice. I suppose the book wants me to do the exercise with only root space decompositions, but I'm happy to see which property of root systems could help solve this problem too.

Comment: Alright. It occurred to me that one might be able to show that second part of (ii) much faster from the first via the Jacobi identity.

Comment: For such a question the assumptions on the ground field should be specified. (Well, from the last line one understands that the field is the complex field.)